# Linux: Permission denied when tried to run a Linux Script

Tags: linux

When i tried toe execute a Script for running a java program   under Linux , it started giving this

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./mail.log (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:177)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:102)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:272)
```

Please let me know , how can i resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Give write permission to `mail.log` to the user running the script. (Running the script as `root` might look simpler but is not a good idea from a security standpoint, so I would recommend against it.)

Comment: I am the user who is running those scripts and i am not a root user , can i give permissions to myself ?

Comment: You set the correct permissions on the file. `chmod 775 mail.log`

Comment: @yyy, maybe `mail.log` does not exist in the current folder, and you don't have write permissions to that folder so the logging engine cannot create the file. In any case, you will have to ask an administrator (or to become one, e.g. through the `su` command) in order to grant the necessary permissions in you're not the owner of the file / folder.

Comment: means as  a user , can i execute  chmod 775 on someone's folder ?

Comment: @yyy, nope, you have to be the owner or `root`.

Answer (score 0):

do you have permission to execute the script? To change a file permission to execut-able use

```
chmod +x <FILENAME>
```